# Cannot add proper bleed in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, bleed

I'm having a little problem in Illustrator CS6 that makes me very confused.I'm trying to extend my file to the "bleed" grid,but the extended background is transparent,which then results in a blank space bleed.How could i fix it,it only happens with this file?[image]

Comment: You should update this question with a screenshot of your layers panel.  That would help answer your question. Also, Is there a clipping mask?

Answer (score 1):

You need to also expand your artboard and your background (red) so there's color behind it.

Using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> or selecting it on the toolbar.

[image]

Source: I work for a printing company so I do this for art daily.

Comment: Bleed should extend past the artboard.

Comment: @GoofyMonkey Unless the artboard is to the piece size+bleed then it will ignore any art not within the artboard. Maybe reconsider downvoting before you know all the facts.

Comment: The FACT, is that "Bleed is a printing term that is used to describe a document which has images or elements that touch the edge of the page, EXTENDING BEYOND THE TRIM EDGE and leaving no white margin." ~ https://rubiks.ca/EN/resource-center/useful-printing-tips.html

Comment: @GoofyMonkey: If I have a 10 x 10 trim and I provide a document 10.25 x 10.25 with manual trim guides for 10 x 10, I have provided bleed. Re-read what Ovaryraptor wrote. Certainly Ovaryraptor knows the definition of bleed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Simulate colored paper` then that appears correct. The simulation **won't** extend into the bleed area, and it shouldn't since it's intent is to *simulate the stock*. Because that color is *not* to be printed, it shouldn't bleed.

If that is merely a rectangle filled with color. Increase the size of the rectangle to hit your bleed guides.

Comment: You see,i'm not very aware of Adobe ,i just started using it.Putting it this way,is there anyway to extend the background of file,so i can print it with 5 mm bleed (which is requested by the print company)? Isn't "bleed" adding extended background,so you can print the file properly?

Comment: Again, I don't know if you are using the `Simulate Colored Paper` option. That makes a difference. If you **are** using that, there's nothing you need to do. The *paper* won't extend into the bleed. It would help if you [edit](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/104724/edit) the question and describe how that background color is set up.

Comment: The file is not created in Illustrator,it is created in online based design site.I open it the same way i open any other file(And adding bleed to them is not a problem),and yet this happens.And no,i'm not using Simulate Colored Paper.

Comment: If it's not created in Illustrator.. why do you state it is? How can anyone help if we don't know the "online based design site"? Sorry, there are so many unknown variables presented with every post you make, I don't think I can help you beyond what I've already posted.

Comment: I think David means the original was created online and he's trying to modify it in Illustrator?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have two boxes to extend. The first one is the pattern, which you've extended, the other should be the solid colour box that is behind your pattern. You should be able to select both boxes at once and extend them. If not, double check that all objects are unlocked, then try to select the colored background box and extend it.

Object > Unlock all

Comment: GoofyMonkey,you are the man.Thank you so much,you explained in such an easy way,and it was followed by success.Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.